# What is the best way to defeat the breeder on nightfall in Call of Duty:Ghosts Extinction?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

The question is pretty cut-and-dry. How to most efficiently kill the breeder(aka the first boss) on Nightfall?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It'll charge up and spew a barrage of bullets your way. When you see it prepare for this, find cover – behind a building, under some rocks, anywhere. Otherwise, you'll be instantly killed by the gunfire. The beast also fires red orbs from its tail, which rain down toxic mist in certain areas of the map. Watch where these attacks go, and avoid these areas until they're clear. Otherwise, you're dead. It also launches yellow eggs that hatch aliens, and they're a pain to deal with while focusing on the Breeder. Destroy them as soon as you can.

Sentry guns are a huge asset in this fight, provided they're facing the Breeder head-on, since its face is the primary weak point. Shoot him only in the red part of his face. Otherwise, save the turrets for secondary duty, like wiping out eggs.

Use your special weapons from the lockers whenever you can. Eventually, the Breeder will make a run for it, and you'll need to face off against a horde of aliens before running into it again. Destroy the last of the Hives as soon as possible, as you'll want to make sure the area is clear of smaller aliens before running head-on into the Breeder.

Deal more damage to the Breeder when it returns, but watch out for waves of enemies when it climbs up the building (usually when it’s down to half damage). It's here where you'll utilize your special weapons, as well as turrets to survive the fight. The Rhinos are particularly tough when they charge, so be prepared to move quickly.

As the Breeder returns, keep an eye out for flower-shaped Hives on the ground. These are small and easy to miss, but they are essential for the Breeder to continue fighting, as they act as fuel. Destroying them will assure it continues taking damage, so make them a priority while avoiding the Breeder's attacks.

For weapons choice MK32 grenade launcher, Maverick, LSAT. BUT make sure you hit it in the face or you're just shooting tampons.﻿

**TL;DR:**

- Attack him while he is standing still, other times he will launch
  eggs and you have to focus on them.
- Shoot only his ugly red face or you are wasting ammo.
- Use LSAT/MK32/Maverick.

Comment: Achievement Unlocked: Answered with an Achievement Worthy Response -- 260R

Answer (score 1):

The gstest way to kill the breeder is with solflams found in searches then with heavy fire from a turret, death machine or also a powerful machine gun like the lsat. The only way to hurt the breeder is in its red eye. Special ammo accept stun. Armor percing ammo is the best. Semtexs also help kill the breeder. It is best to have two or more people killing the breeder because of all of the aliens and the heavy spraying of bullets fired every 20 to 30 second and right as you can start hurting it. Getting behind a building prevents you getting hurt by the scorpion like gas but stronger and the spraying of bullets. Hopefully you take my advice.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to defeat the breeder twice.

In the first encounter, I find that the quickest method is standing right in front of it, going no further than the wall corner on your left/right.  Unload your ammo into its face, obviously with your best gun (ark attachment on your pistol is very effective).  You need to see the red hit marker to know you are aiming correctly.

The only time you don't want to be shooting it in the face:

- When your character shouts something along the lines of it getting ready to fire/attack, run to the left or right out of its sights (it will crouch down and fire for a few seconds - if you get caught in this you will get downed)
- Enemies are hitting you from behind (kill them off quickly) - helps to have a stowed shield to absorb some damage before you can react
- You need to shift left or right because it has fired its red liquid in your location

In the second encounter I would recommend bringing a venom-x gun with you.  Use this as well as shooting it in the face.  Half way through the battle it will retreat, which is when you will have to deal with a lot of aliens spawning.  Once you have cleared most of the aliens he will be back.  Repeat a combination of venom-x and your best gun to bring it down.

You will probably want to be near some cover in the final part so that you can use it when it starts firing.  You'll also need to be more aware of the aliens in this battle too (more so than the first encounter).  Use turrets, shields and armour to keep yourself protected.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to kill the breeder is to use a non explosive type of ammo (explosive works but less effectively) and use the MTS (or bulldog) with your weapon specialists ability and while the breeder is shooting out his poison red sacks in the air walk right in front of the breeder activate your weapon specialist ability and fire away at his face

Answer (score -4):

The best way to kill a breeder is to stand far away and shoot while backing up. Another method is to stand at the top of the stairs where the mini-turret is and use it while the breeder comes to you.

Comment: Telling people to go watch videos is not at all helpful.

Comment: ya it is!!!!!!!

Comment: No, it's not.  You have other useful information here, so I have removed that sentence to allow it to help others.

Comment: I'm just trying to help someone you don't have to be a jerk

Comment: also yes it is I gave an answer and gave a helpful link if my answer did not help and where to find another one

Comment: Your answer information, I'm not disputing.  I'm pointing out that, "go watch videos" is singularly unhelpful for *anything*.  That doesn't help anyone at all.  What videos should they watch?  What should they search for?  Is there one that's really helpful?  That's what I'm pointing out.  "Go watch videos" is too general to be of use.  Point out WHICH video to watch, and why it helps the reader.

Comment: dear Frank, sorry for the disturbance. the person your where talking with was my brother. (whitch I share a account with) says he is very sorry. Thank you for the comments to his answer.